# Summation of series (proof)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image][image] 
I need help with this question. I tried, but couldn't do it. How do I approach it? 
[image] 
I tried this approach. The problem is, even though it's obvious (by intuition) that the series (A1+A2+A3+......) adds up to less than 1, I can't show it that it does indeed add up to less than 1. Because the series is irregular, without a pattern. How do I prove it? I don't even know if this is the right approach, so please help me with it. Thanks

Comment: Thoughts: Maybe you can compare it to a geometric sum. You could come up with a geometric sum whose values are close but still bigger to the $A$-terms.

Comment: Thanks, but would it be convincing enough? Good enough, I mean? The series has no pattern. It's not an AP, a GP, or an HP, an AGP... Also, using methods of difference doesn't get us anywhere. I really tried it, but couldn't find a way to add the series. I tried to find a pattern

Comment: Is there any other way I can prove it?

Comment: What I mean is that one way of proving that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n A_k <1
$$
is to find another series, $B_n$ so that $A_n \leq B_n$ and for which it is easy to show that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n B_k <1
$$
So then
$$
A_k \leq B_k \Rightarrow 
\sum_{k=1}^n A_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^n B_k \leq 1
$$

Comment: Maybe compare $A_k$ to, let's say,
$$
B_k = \frac{1}{2^{k+2}}
$$

Comment: How can you compare $A_n$ to a geometric series ??? $\frac{A_n}{A_n-1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$, so $A_n$ will ultimately become larger than any convergent geometric sequence.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious here. In the limit, $A_n\to A_{n-1}$ and you might as well expect a diverging series.

Comment: By simplifying the fractions, you kill the opportunities to find a pattern in the numerators.

Comment: I found the solution, but couldn't understand it fully. It makes sense until the 4th step. From fifth step onwards, doesn't quite make sense. Can you explain it please?

Answer (score 1):

First you can prove that the sum converges (this step is not necessary, but interesting by itself) :
$$\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}} = 1-\frac{3}{2n}$$
Find a new sequence of the form $B_n=n^{-\alpha}$ such that $\alpha>1$ and $\frac{B_n}{B_{n-1}}>\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}}$ :
$$\frac{B_n}{B_{n-1}} = (\frac{n-1}{n})^\alpha = 1-\frac{\alpha}{n}+o(\frac1n)$$
If you take $\alpha=\frac54$, you can conclude that $\frac{B_n}{B_{n-1}}>\frac{A_n}{A_{n-1}}$ for sufficiently large $n$, which leads to $A_n<B_n$ for $n>N_0$. As $\sum B_n$ converges, so does $\sum A_n$ (this is known as the Raabe-Duhamel criterion in France).

Now note $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n A_k$. From $2nA_n=(2n-3)A_{n-1}$ follows :
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 2kA_k = 2A_1+\sum_{k=2}^n (2k-3)A_{k-1} = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (2k-1)A_k = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2kA_k - S_{n-1}$$
By subtracting the terms present on both side of this last equation, you are down to :
$$S_{n-1}=1-2nA_n$$
This by itself is enough to prove $S_n<1$ for all $n$ (the convergence of $\sum A_n$ is useless, it is sufficient to prove that $A_n>0$ for all $n$), but it gives the sum of the series :
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_n=1$$
This is because we proved that $A_n<n^{-5/4}$ for sufficiently large $n$.